# PHP move information between SQL Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to move information from Table A to Table B with the following code. in the same time I want to delete the row in table B once information is moved to table A

```
 //Move from table A to table B
        $sql = "insert into del_ussd_members SELECT * FROM members WHERE 
 member_id='$member_id'";    

if (mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
            $insertSuccessful = true;
        } else {
            echo $sql;
            print_r($_POST);
           echo "\n" . mysql_error($con);             echo "mysql err no : " .   
 mysql_errno($con);
        }
 //Delete from members
        $sql2 = "DELETE FROM members WHERE member_id='$member_id'";      

if (mysql_query($sql1, $con)) {
         $insertSuccessful = true;
      } else {
           echo $sql1;
          echo "\n" . mysql_error($con);
          echo "mysql err no : " . mysql_errno($con);
        }
```

The move is happening no problem but the delete function gives me the following error

```
 Query was emptymysql err no : 1065
```

Even if I run the string on its own I get the same error

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thanks all typing error missed that it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
if (mysql_query($sql1, $con)) {  //because $sql1 doesn't exist as per your code.
```

with

```
if (mysql_query($sql2, $con)) {
```

<sup>You should first change mysql_* functions to mysqli or PDO. Because the whole mysql_* functions will be deprecated in the coming versions.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

There is no `$sql1` variable in your code so you can't use it. You probably wanted to use `$sql2`.

Also, think about moving to `PDO` or `mysqli_*`, because `mysql_*` is deprecated and will be removed from PHP.

Next thing is that your first query is incorrect. Split it to two separated queries.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change `$sql1` to `$sql2` in second query.

```
  //Delete from members

  $sql2 = "DELETE FROM members WHERE member_id='$member_id'";      

   if (mysql_query($sql2, $con)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy Paste:

```
//Move from table A to table B
        $sql = "insert into del_ussd_members SELECT * FROM members WHERE 
 member_id='$member_id'";    

if (mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
            $insertSuccessful = true;
        } else {
            echo $sql;
            print_r($_POST);
           echo "\n" . mysql_error($con);             echo "mysql err no : " .   
 mysql_errno($con);
        }
 //Delete from members
        $sql2 = "DELETE FROM members WHERE member_id='$member_id'";      

if (mysql_query($sql2, $con)) {
         $insertSuccessful = true;
      } else {
           echo $sql2;
          echo "\n" . mysql_error($con);
          echo "mysql err no : " . mysql_errno($con);
        }
```